# Text in TextArea on AIR mobile app disappears after displaying for a moment

Tags: apache-flex, air, textarea, flex4.5

I'm having a very odd issue where I am trying to use a text area to display some text on a mobile AIR app. It works fine whenever I am using the phone emulator on my desktop to debug, however whenever I put the app on my phone, the text displays, then disappears. I've also noticed that if I lock the screen and unlock, the text will display just fine when I come back.

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Program Overview">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        private var text:String = "Hey how are ya";
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextArea text="{text}" editable="false" />

</s:View>
```

One other interesting thing to note is that it only happens on certain Views, and only on Views in the first ViewNavigator tab. This leads me to believe that there isn't really anything wrong with my use of the TextArea, but something else happening at a higher level in the application. Any ideas on what I should look for?

Comment: I've definitely seen some weird issues with regard to TextAreas and the 4.6 SDK when running on mobile with ice cream sandwich, in the emulator everything was good for me too using the soft keyboard I was getting random characters re-inserted (as though fetched from a buffer but the buffer wasn't properly updated or something).  More on mobile and text here, but no real good reason this is a problem: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c6a9f451212b87fe7e87-7fff.html#WS19f279b149e7481c6a9f451212b87fe7e87-7ffd maybe give versions of device OS and Flex/AIR version.

Comment: If you can, try StyleableTextField instead of TextArea. From my experience, it works pretty good on Android and iOS devices. Haven't got around to test it with ICS though.

Comment: Why use TextArea if it isn't going to be editable?  Why not just use Label?  Also, try updating to 4.6 SDK.  There's been some major changes to text for mobile in 4.6.

Comment: @J_A_X I'm not using Label because I need to be able to style the text. (Once it's working that is)  -user1069487 Thanks, I'll give that a shot    -shaunhusain I am on 4.6, but not trying to run on ICS, just Gingerbread, it's definitely wacky how it isn't working on the phone, but is on the emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up replacing all of my TextArea's with StyleableTextFields as @Al_Birdy suggested and that took care of the issue. Because you can only use them in AS it made layout and styling a little bit more difficult but it was definitely worth the fix.

Answer (score 3):

I think than the problem can be solved if you add the skinClass:

this is for TextArea:

```
<s:TextArea id="text1" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin" text="{myVar}"/>
```

this is fot TextInput:

```
<s:TextInput id="text2" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" text="{myVar}"/>
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563788/