# Flex Mobile 4.6 Textinput Databinding

Tags: apache-flex, textinput

the new TextInput component which uses stagetext on 4.6 has this issue where if you bind a variable on it e.g
view1...

and i push a new view e.g view2, and pop it, hence reloading view1.
on initial load, I can see that the textinput display the variable abruptly then the text vanishes afterwards..

I'd like to note that the variable is a stored data, and can be access on any view.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think than the problem can be solved if you add the skinClass:

this is for TextArea:

```
<s:TextArea id="text1" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin" text="{myVar}"/>
```

this is fot TextInput:

```
<s:TextInput id="text2" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" text="{myVar}"/>
```

I hope this help you!